# TOTAL CHANNEL POWER WHEN 1% IS -33.9 dBm

Tags: decibel

If a power meter measures 1% of the total channel power to be -33.9dBm, what is  the total channel power?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not a programming question. [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score 0):

The key concept here is that dBs enable the use of addition vs. multiplication:

```
Pt[in Watts] = 100 * Pm[in Watts]  ==>
Pt[in dBm's] = 10 log10(100) + Pm[in dBm's] =
               20            + -33.9 =
-13.9dBm

Check:
Pm = (10^(-33.9dBm/10))*0.001 = 0.000000407380278 Watts
Pt = (10^(-13.9dBm/10))*0.001 = 0.00004073802778 Watts

Pt[in milliWatts] = 100 * Pm[in milliWatts] =
0.00004073802778 =? 100 * 0.000000407380278 =
0.0000407380278
```